# Magento 2 order id and increment_id

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 what is the difference between `order Id` and order `increment_id`?

For example  `getAllIds()` returns order ids and the results of say `$collection->getColumnValues('increment_id')` returns `increment_id`s

Also when I view an order on the dashboard, it looks to be the `increment_id`

Comment: It's the same in Magento 1: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/26250/243

Answer (score 2, accepted):

order Id(entity_id) is ***the primary key of sales order table*** and it is `not visible at customer end`.

And ***increment_id is also an auto increment field basic of  place order store ***.Customer `only see it and  it is structural and always started store id`, just like  100000049 and 300000214,where starting numbers (1,3)  is  ids of store. 1,3 are those store's ids  from order is placed.